# BDC update operation fails with socket exception

Tags: external-content-type, bdc

I have set up an `external content type` in my `BDC Service`, and I am using the `Secure Store Service` to provide the database credentials.

In the `ECT` I have set up Read Item, Read List, and Update Item operations.  The read operations seem to work - when I add an external data column to a `list`, I can see all the items from the database in the `picker`, and if I choose one it pulls in the correct data for the column (and related columns).

However, if I try to update one of the columns, the request eventually times out, and if I look at the `ULS logs`, I can see a bunch of repeated attempts to perform the update, but they all fail with:

> Possibly the host name 'SQL_SharePoint13_Dev2' is invalid and it's could not be found. The exception is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known

The SQL instance is on a different server, but SP Designer (run on the WFE) found it using that name (or I wouldn't have been able to make the ECT), and the read operations work.

I tried Googling the error, but the only things I found had to do with permissions on the Secure Store service, and making sure the correct port was open on the server that can't be connected to.  I don't think it's the Secure Store Service, since the reads work.  When you write to SQL, does it go through a different port than when you read?  Even if it does, that doesn't make sense to me as the problem since SharePoint is working in general, so all those DB writes are occurring just fine.

So, what could be some of the reasons for this error when attempting an ECT update operation?

Comment: I'm guessing since I don't know your server nor farm-setup but a few thing rings a bell. Do you use SQL Alias pointing to the actual destination as in FQDN? From the looks of things, SQL_SharePoint13_Dev2 seems like the SQl Server in the farm but BDC by definition is another SQL server or at least another instance on the same SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @BennySkogberg, I will ask about the SQL Alias setup.  The database that I am connecting to through BDC is on the same server and instance as all the SharePoint DBs, though.

Comment: @BennySkogberg it seems that yes, `SQL_Sharepoint13_Dev2` is an alias pointing to the FQDN.  Does that mean I have to set up the connection for the ECT using the FQDN instead of the alias?